# Farsi regular expressions with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, farsi

I don't know much about Ruby, but I have this line of code that I would like to know what it exactly does:

```
newline.gsub!(/\s+(های)\s+/,'‌\1 ')
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Reading the documentation is always a really good starting point. It doesn't look like you expended much energy doing that. A very simple Google search for ["ruby gsub"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+gsub) would have started you on your path to answering your question. That would have led you to looking up ["ruby regexp"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression matches if a string contains the persian phrase with **one or more** whitespace characters around it (both at the front and back).

Then it replaces it with the string `\1`. The `\1` refers to the first matched element. So, it removes all the whitespace around the string and adds one space after the element.

**Example**

I am taking the value `test` instead of the Parsi phrase, because unicode wasn't working out.

```
newline = "    test   "
=> "    test   "
newline.gsub!(/\s+(test)\s+/,'\1 ') 
=> "test "
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What is the meaning of \1 ?

Comment: `\1` is the first matching element within the regexp. Here it is the element with the brackets. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) says:

```
gsub!(pattern, replacement) → str or nil
```

So your expression would return the substituted string if it matched the pattern, else return `nil`.  (Essentially remove all the whitespaces before the *farsi* string and replace the ones following it with a *single* whitespace.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since Farsi language is written right to left, did you mean: it remove all the whitespaces after the Farsi string and replace the ones before it with a single whitespace?